# X509Store is empty in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, x509certificate2

I have the following user credentials in my Android device:

[image]

I tried to find them in the `X509Store` with every combination of the `StoreName` and `StoreLocation`, but *none* of them is found:

```
using (var store = new X509Store(StoreName.TrustedPeople, StoreLocation.CurrentUser))
{
   store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
   foreach (var item in store.Certificates)
   {
     //do your job
   }
}
```

I need to verify if a certain certification is installed.

Any idea how to access that list?

Comment: Has this been solved already?

Comment: @dmoore1181 No, the question still stands. I'm not sure where to look for a solution.